# Loops and increasing letter values for cells in string grid

Tags: delphi

So this could be hard to explain but i want to do a for ... := 1 to 10 do statement but i want it to be for A to N do. The main purpose of this excersise is to load data into a string grid. So lets have it load the cells 0,1 0,2 0,3 0,4 0,5 0,6 0,7 with the Letter A, B, C, D, E all the way up to 14. If anyone knows how to do this i would be extremely thankful!

Answer (score 6):

Here you got it, but I'm not sure if it's a good way how to learn programming (I mean asking question as requests so that someone else write code for you):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  StringGrid1.FixedCols := 1;
  StringGrid1.ColCount := 15;
  for I := 1 to 14 do
    StringGrid1.Cells[I, 1] := Chr(Ord('A') + I - 1);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fill the StringGrid control one row at a time, you can do

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  StringGrid1.FixedCols := 1;
  StringGrid1.FixedRows := 1;
  for i := 0 to Min(25, (StringGrid1.ColCount-1) * (StringGrid1.RowCount-1)) do
    StringGrid1.Cells[i mod (StringGrid1.ColCount - 1) + 1,
      i div (StringGrid1.ColCount - 1) + 1] := Chr(Ord('A') + i);
end;
```

which works no matter how many rows and cols there are.

Comment: @TLama: No need to delete your post! You were first, and perhaps Matt actually just wants to fill the first row. Our answers complement eachother. In addition, to an absolute beginner, while your code might be comprehensible, my might be very non-transparent (a huge amount of +-1's, and the very odd `mod` operator, not to mention the `Min` which is hidden in the `Math` unit).

Comment: Ok, you've convinced me to undelete :-) However, Matt can use part of your code, I think. It seems that [`buttons`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11806495/960757) won't be used after all.

Answer (score 0):

Want to fuse TLama's answer with that "want to do a for ... := 1 to 10 do statement but i want it to be for A to N do"

Don't know if it will be pun, or enlightening.

```
var c: char; i: integer;
    s: string;  
    ...
  i := 0; s:= EmptyStr;
  for c := 'A' to 'N' do begin
      s := s + c + ',';
      Inc(i);
  end;

  SetLength(s, Length(s) - 1); // we do not need last comma there
  StringGrid1.ColCount := i;
  StringGrid1.Rows[0].CommaText := s;
```

Or the same using TStringBuilder - which would be faster than re-arranging Heap on each new string modification.

```
uses SysUtils;
    ...
var c: char; i: integer;
    s: string;
    ...
  i := 0;
  with TStringBuilder.Create do try
     for c := 'A' to 'N' do begin
         Append(c + ',');
         Inc(i);
     end;
     s := ToString;
  finally 
     Free;
  end;

  SetLength(s, Length(s) - 1); // we do not need last comma there
  StringGrid1.ColCount := i;
  StringGrid1.Rows[0].CommaText := s;
```

Comment: Well, i basically wanted to display use of char loop, since original question sounds like it. You may do like *.Cells[1+ord(c)-ord('A'), 1] := c* as well. Or you may have *array of char* as substitute to StringBuilder. But that would all hamper clarity. And even on simple object like StringGrid i won't gambple which is faster, single call to CommaText setter with internal parsing and maybe internal structures using or looped calls to Cells setter. Probably i am biased by seeing a lot of *TDataSet.Fields['some-stirng'] := any-var;* snippets instead of something like TDataSet.AppendRecord :-)

Comment: @TLama, would you revive your comment or what ? i'm lost.

Comment: Let it be :-) I realized that you can use a constant string like `A,B,C,D...` instead of loop concatenation. That's why I've deleted my comment.

Comment: i thought about constant. But that would require separace ColCount constant and the risk to get out of sync in later maintenance. Or special counting routine polluting the sample. Or soem StringSplit->array/TStrings to just get the length, which would be even less effecient. So afterall i preferred to just have a simple loop and an abvious counter to ensure i always have the correct count. That surely is not most optimal way to do, but, well, no one even used BeginUpdate above :-P

Comment: Hmm, one obvious replacement for StringBuilder in this case would be using TStringList itself. Then he would probably just have do *StringGrid1.Rows[0] := my-string-list;* :-) Though probably for incremental filling StringList is much worse than StringBuilder